# How to re-run a task if its result fails

Tags: ansible

I have a couple of tasks like this:

```yaml
---
- name: Get md5
  net_command:
    commands:
      - "bash md5sum {{ image }}"
  register: md5_remote


- name: Verify md5
  assert:
    that:
      - md5_local in md5_remote.stdout[0]
  register: md5_result
  until: "md5_result is not failed"
  retries: 5
  delay: 60
```

Note that `net_command` is a custom module we use for some specific networking equipment that does not have any builtin Ansible modules.

So what I am trying to do is to re-run the `Get md5` task if the `Verify md5` assertion fails.  Right now it's just looping over `Verify md5` without actually re-calculating the checksum again, so, if it fails once it will never work complete.

So, basically, I need to recaculate the checksum multiple times until it matches the expected one, stored in `md5_local`.

Comment: Your `until` should simply be in your `net_command` task.

Comment: but the md5sums are not compared in the `net_command` task.  Are you saying that the `assert` and `until` stuff should be moved under the `net_command` task?

Comment: No, the `until` is an assertion already, so, simply: `until: "md5_local in md5_remote.stdout[0]"`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to retry a task, you'll have to put the `until` loop on that task. Since `until` is an assertion already, there is no need for a separate `assert` task.

So, your use case should be covered by a single task:

```yaml
- name: Get md5
  net_command:
    commands:
      - "bash md5sum {{ image }}"
  register: md5_remote
  until: md5_local in md5_remote.stdout[0]
  retries: 5
  delay: 60
```